# Increment Number in ZSH script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to create directories based off of the number of files I have in a directory and my approach is a loop.

I am keeping track of the number by a number variable and want to increment it as so after each even number, create a directory.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/zsh

LOOP=$(ls 2021/*.xlsx)
totalFiles=$(ls 2021/*.xlsx | wc -l)
directoryCount=0
count=0

for FILE in ${LOOP[@]}; do
    echo "BEFORE: $count"
    count=$((count+1))
    echo "AFTER: $count"
    echo $FILE
done

echo "TOTAL FILE: $totalFiles"
echo $count
```

and the output I get is:

```
BEFORE: 0
AFTER: 1
2021/*Tanner2103.xlsx
2021/*Tanner2104.xlsx
2021/*Tanner2105.xlsx
2021/*Tanner2106.xlsx
TOTAL FILE:       4
1
```

I dont understand why count only increments once but the loop is obviously has more iterations than that.

So basically since there are 4 files, I want to split them up into 2 directories, Ill do the logic for that later. But for now Im just trying to get the directory code working.

Comment: You are defining the variable `LOOP` as a scalar, but afterwards access it as if it were an array.

Comment: Don't use `ls`; `LOOP=( 2021/*.xlsx )` will suffice *and* will work for all valid file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I feel silly. I thought that `ls` would come back as an iterable but its actual only return one iteration as a whole.

This is my updated code and it updating like I want.

```
totalFiles=$(ls 2021/*.xlsx | wc -l)

count=0

for FILE in 2021/**/*(.); do
    echo "BEFORE $count"
    echo "$FILE"
    ((count++))
    echo "AFTER $count"
done

echo "TOTAL FILE: $totalFiles"
echo $count


result: 
BEFORE 0
2021/*Tanner2103.xlsx
AFTER 1
BEFORE 1
2021/*Tanner2104.xlsx
AFTER 2
BEFORE 2
2021/*Tanner2105.xlsx
AFTER 3
BEFORE 3
2021/*Tanner2106.xlsx
AFTER 4
TOTAL FILE:       4
4
```

Comment: Don't use `ls`. If you want the number of matching files, `files=(2021/*.xlsx)` and `totalFiles=${#files}`

Comment: `ls` outputs a single string, which might have embedded newlines to separate indivudla files names. But those names could *also* contain newlines, so you can't tell which newlines are part of file names and which separate file names.

Comment: I will note the short hand of the command to list all the files, and thank you for the info. ZSH/Bash is something I want to learn more about