# How to loop files while tracking current file number? How to loop enumerated files in zsh?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

How can I loop over a list of files and also access the current loop iteration number?

Something like:

```
for i, file in mydir/*; do echo $i $file; done
```

desired output:

```
1 one.txt
2 three.txt
3 two.txt
```

Comment: Does this address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922804/ ?

Comment: This looks more like a general programming question. Before entering the loop, you initialize a counter, and in every iteration you increment the counter.

Comment: @user1934428 there's no shorthand in zsh?

Comment: No, and it is rarely needed (I think). For instance, I would probably not use a loop in your case, but pipe the lines into `nl`, which then takes care about the numbering. See _man nl_.

Comment: Piping the lines to `nl` is not ideal, because filenames can, in theory, contain newlines.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use an array, and have the array index act as the `loop iteration number':

```bash
typeset -a files=(*.txt)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    print -r -- ${files[(ie)$file]} $file
exit
```

As a function, with a shortened form of the loop:

```bash
> listWithIndex() {
    for arg ("${argv[@]}") print -r -- ${argv[(ie)$arg]} $arg
}
> ls -1 *.txt
one.txt
three.txt
two.txt
> listWithIndex *.txt
1 one.txt
2 three.txt
3 two.txt
```

There are more details about getting the index of an array element [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334048/obtain-the-index-of-the-array).

---

Edited to add: with an anonymous function, we can do everything in a single line:

```bash
(){for a; print -r -- $@[(i)$a] $a} *.txt
```

Comment: For reference, the behavior of the subscript `(ie)$file` is described in the Subscript Flags section of `man zshparam`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit loop counter - in my opinion it would be a waste of resources, as it is seldom needed.

There are many ways to skin that cat, I would go with the counter in the answer linked by user1934428, but you can also use the equivalent

```bash
files=(mydir/*); 
for ((i = 1; i <= ${#files[@]}; i++)) echo ${i} ${files[$i]}
```